# python - threading and infinite loops

Tags: python, multithreading

inside the main python script, at a point variable `VAR` is set and thread `THR` is executed with variable `VAR` as starting value.
within `THR` there's an infinite loop, which prints `VAR` every 500 *ms*.
meanwhile the main script crunches some more data and `VAR` is updated.

how do I reflect the change to `THR`, so that the printed output will change as well, without killing it and spawning a new one?

this is a very rough simplification of the code I have of course, but I'd rather read and focus on an example skeleton rather than on my particular case.

EDIT: as per request here's the code I have in mind

```
import threading

VAR = 0

def function():
    while True:
        global VAR
        while VAR == VAR:
            print VAR
            time.sleep(0.5)

THR = threading.Thread(target=function)
THR.start()
time.sleep(1)
function().VAR = 4 # this doesn't affect the output, only adds a seemingly random whitespace before it
time.sleep(2)
THR.VAR = 5 # nothing changes
```

Comment: Paste your code please.

Comment: Or better post a minimal example which reproduces the error/problem you have. Does something actually not work? It sounds like everything should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a list with your variable inside.

If you pass the list to the function, you will be able to modify the value of the first position of the list (outside the function) and at the same time you'll see how the thread prints the correct value.

Pseudocode:

```
(THREAD)
    while True:
        print list[0]

(MAIN)
    start_thread(list)
    #modify value
    list[0] = X
```

Comment: that was it, perfect. can you please briefly explain why **VAR** has to be wrapped inside a list for **THR** to notice it?

Comment: When you pass the variable to the Thread it is only getting the VALUE but if you're using a list you will pass the memory address (if the value changes outside, it will change too inside).